# How to add two dto for one query param?

Tags: nestjs, class-validator

I want to use two dto's for one query param.

```
@Query() query: CurrencyTypeDto|PaginationLimitDto
```

I know I can use inheritance. Maybe there is another way?

Answer (score 2):

`NestJs` offers something called `IntersectionType()` to combine two types into one new type (dto), to Implement that you need to:

```
    export class queryDto extends IntersectionType(
  CurrencyTypeDto,
  PaginationLimitDto,
) {}
```

then you can use it: `@Query() query: queryDto`

*Ref : [intersection](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/mapped-types#intersection)*